# CSS 3 opacity transition doesnt work for <img>

Tags: image, css, opacity, transformation

I have several images embedded in various s. Now I want to add an opacity transformation (CSS3).
The code is:

```
.divbgs img {

opacity: 0.5;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;

}
.divbgs img:hover {
opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ;

}
```

Each image is embedded into its own div. I want to put text there later.

```
<img src="/img/rook/img/cenote.jpg" class="divbgs"/>
```

But the effect just wont work. I have used it in another page a few months ago and there it does work fine with the same code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selector is wrong

<s>`.divbgs img`</s>

It's `img.divbgs` & `img.divbgs:hover`

Comment: or, alternatively, the embedding div (not shown in the code) should also have the divbgs class.

Comment: Hey, it still doesnt work
i put the complete souce code in my question now.

Comment: @valh your question is still the same, plz check it.

Comment: sorry it works now ive put the imgs in a div and set the effect for the div